# Load ViewController Swift - Black Screen

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, navigation

Im trying to simply load a new ViewController and its associated xib when a button is clicked, but the screen becomes black after the new view is loaded. When the button is clicked the following method is called:

```
    let vc = MainViewController()
    self.showViewController(vc, sender: nil)
```

I am able to debug and see that we are jumping into the viewDidLoad method of the new "MainViewController" class, but the UI is not rendering and the screen is black. I have set the File's Owner of MainViewController.xib to the MainViewController.swift class, but nothing happens. super() is being called in the class as well. The only thing in MainViewController.xib is a MapView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, your are missing name of xib...

```
 let vc = MainViewController(nibName: "MainViewController", bundle: nil) // Enter you nibname in this 
 self.showViewController(vc, sender: nil)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. Thanks for the help!