# Switching to New View Controller does not Activate XIB File

Tags: ios, swift, pushviewcontroller

I'm new to Swift, and the class I took taught me without storyboards, so just putting that as a caveat.

I'm trying to build my own app now, and I'm trying to push a new viewController onto the main navigation controller. This works fine, but when I go to the new viewController, it doesn't ever load what I put in the xib file. That is, I know it's going to the right place because I can change background color, etc., in code, but I've put some elements in the xib and they're not showing up. I saw this discussion: [Load ViewController Swift - Black Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555004/load-viewcontroller-swift-black-screen) and did what it said, but it's still not helping.

Here's my push code:

```
var viewController = CreateViewController(nibName: "CreateViewController", bundle: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Alternately, and this is probably a better question — I haven't gotten that far yet. Should I just try to learn storyboards? It's not that complicated of an app and everyone seems to say storyboards are better...

Comment: What does your xib file look like? File's Owner set to `UIViewController` plus a view object, or separate View Controller object, or both? Also, how are you adding elements to the xib - are you using AutoLayout and adding constraints?

Comment: Shows how much my class taught me. How do I set the File's Owner? I have a separate CreateViewController.swift file, and I created the xib (CreateViewController.xib) at the same time with the interface. The view is in theory a UITabBarController. I'm adding elements like you said, using AutoLayout and constraining, though right now I just have a big text button in the middle to test it.

Comment: Annnd I think I figured it out. Can you not have xib files for TabBarControllers? When I deleted that file, gave up, and just started creating the views within that, it seemed to work. So, for now, I think I'm set... Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, a `UITabBarController` is a container view controller. You don't add views to this type of view controller - instead, they present "child" view controllers, which can present their own content. You create a content view controller (often a subclass of `UIViewController`), then you add it as a child by setting the `viewControllers` property on your tab bar view controller.